# What is the use of Euler Totient or Phi Function?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, education

What is most motivating way of introducing this function? Does it in itself have any real life applications that have an impact. I can only think of a^phi(n)=1 (mod n) which is   powerful result but is this function used elsewhere.

Comment: $\phi (n)$ is also the size of the group of units of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n\mathbb{Z}}$, as a ring.

Comment: Equivalently but without any abstract algebra: $\phi(n)$ is the number of integers smaller than $n$ which are coprime relative to $n$.

Comment: $\phi(n)$ is also $[\mathbb Q(e^{2\pi i/n}):\mathbb Q]$.

Comment: What do you mean by "real life"?

Comment: I think the comment given by Chris Dugale is more or less the main point: $\varphi(n)$ is the size of a certain finite group, the units mod $n$, which shows up in many places. If you think the finite matrix groups ${\rm GL}_d({\mathbf Z}/(n))$ are worthwhile then you probably would want to know how big they are. The simplest case $d = 1$ corresponds exactly to the units mod $n$, with size $\varphi(n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RSA, or public-key cryptography is one of them.

Comment: RSA only needs the case $n = pq$ with distinct primes $p$ and $q$, so it is a very limited use of the $\varphi$-function.